# HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Problem in Firefox, but ok with Internet Explorer.
I tried a lot but not solve yet. Please help me.

Actually the problem over here is that, it is not in formatte order in firefox. but is displaying on in internet explorer.

```
<html>  
  <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>  
    <title>HOME</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown.css" type="text/css" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dropdown.js"></script>  
    <!-- /* below javascript function is to handle the "Enter" key form submission */ -->  
    <script language="javascript">  
    </script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      function change1(){  
        document.getElementById('id1').style.display='block'  
        document.getElementById('id2').style.display='none'  
        document.getElementById('id3').style.display='block'  
        document.getElementById('id4').style.display='none'  
        document.getElementById('body1').style.display='block'  
        document.getElementById('body2').style.display='none'  
        document.home_page.reg_id.focus();  
      }  
      function change2(){  
        document.getElementById('id1').style.display='none'  
        document.getElementById('id2').style.display='block'  
        document.getElementById('id3').style.display='none'    
        document.getElementById('id4').style.display='block'    
        document.getElementById('body1').style.display='none'    
        document.getElementById('body2').style.display='block'    
        document.home_page.uname.focus();  
      }  
    </script>  
    <!-- end of "enter" key handling functions. -->  
  </head>  


<form method="POST" action="home_page.php" name="home_page">  
  <table width="320" height="200" border="1">  
    <tr style="width:315px;" align="center">  
    <td align="center" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;" bgcolor="#000099" width="155" height="28" id="id1" onClick="change1()"></td>  
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#009900" style="display:none; background-repeat:no-repeat;" width="155" height="28" id="id2" onClick="change1()"></td>  
    <td align="center" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;" bgcolor="#009900" width="155" height="28" id="id3" onClick="change2()"></td>  
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#000099" style="display:none; background-repeat:no-repeat;" width="155" height="28" id="id4" onClick="change2()"></td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
    <td colspan="2" id="body1">  
    <table width="318" height="44" border="0">  
    <tr>  
    <td width="318" height="40" align="center">  
    <span class="loginstyle3">Registration Status</span>  
    </td>  
    </tr>  
    </table></td>  
    <td colspan="2" id="body2" style="display:none;">  
    <table width="318" height="45" border="0">  
    <tr>  
    <td width="107" height="41" align="center" background="images/glossy1grey.gif">  
    <span class="loginstyle3">Login Entry </span>  
    </td>  
    </tr>  
    </table>  
    </td>  
    </tr>  
  </table>  
<!-- below block of code is to set login page after login attempt and failed -->  
<script type="text/javascript">change2()</script>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: I fixed your formatting...but where's your opening `<body>` tag?

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question to get an answer! ;-)

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Have you tried using Firebug? ( http://getfirebug.com/ )

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you divided by zero somewhere... oh sh--

Seriously, what's the problem? Where's the question?

Comment: What the hell is document.home_page.uname.focus(); ?? Btw you should learn proper xHTML and CSS, your page looks like a 1997 website ;)

Comment: @Nick Craver: Sorry! I missed the body tag. but it is present in my html file.
@Salil and @Jhominal: My problem is in mozilla is that. Its formatting is not like i want to see(Which is visible in Internet Explorer8). It is going totally out of controll. The size of colored tab become full strenth in Mozilla, while in IE8, it is ok.

@Michael Lumbroso: Yes, i missed the uname(uname.text). I used that in my project. Becoz of space of complexity, i removed it. It will just throw an javascript error. Just remove that line.

Comment: @all: Copy that code, and test it in both, IE8 and Mozilla.

You all can see the the difference.

Comment: @Michael: Psh.  I agree on the CSS to an extent, but XHTML is quite overrated.  If it's XHTML, it's not HTML; it's XML that kinda looks like HTML, and tends to kinda work because most browsers are already able to cover for some schmuck's broken "HTML".  And it should be served as XHTML (or at least XML) but hardly ever is, because certain huge browsers *cough*IE*cough* don't support it properly either way, but they choke on it less when it's served as HTML.  Add to that, most people who write "XHTML" *don't know how to*, cause XHTML has a different DOM, scripts in CDATA sections, etc etc etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that setting table cells (`<td>` elements) to be "display: block" is going to work out well in Firefox. Table cells have their own "display" type, and if you make them "display: block" the browser is going to do what you ask.  Note that "display: block" is *not* simply the opposite of "display: none".

Try using "display: table-cell" instead of "block".

*edit* — I've tried this and it's definitely what the problem is.

Comment: Great! Thanx a lot. Superb answer. Solve all my problem. 
But ready to get some more question. YOu would must have to attend that. Thanx again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem in FF

```
document.home_page.uname is undefined
Line 27
```

Comment: actually, IE 8 gives the same problem :D

Comment: @Nick Craver: Sorry! I missed the body tag. but it is present in my html file. @Salil and @Jhominal: My problem is in mozilla is that. Its formatting is not like i want to see(Which is visible in Internet Explorer8). It is going totally out of controll. The size of colored tab become full strenth in Mozilla, while in IE8, it is ok. @Michael Lumbroso: Yes, i missed the uname(uname.text). I used that in my project. Becoz of space of complexity, i removed it. It will just throw an javascript error. Just remove that line.
@all:Just copy and paste all the code and then try that with mozilla & IE8

Comment: Your problem, @Anup Prakash, is with your script that's setting table cell elements to be "display: block".  You are explicitly telling the browser not to display those like table cells.

Answer (score 0):

The problems you have are

- your TD is inheriting the height=200 from the TABLE
- your TD has display: block which forces it onto a new line

Why are you using tables for this? They add a lot of extra, unnecessary tags. Have a read up on CSS, it's the future (and the present..)!

Answer (score -1):

The most obvious thing to me is that you use self closing `<LINK>` and `<META>` tags in what is probably not a XHTML file. Those are meant to be left open. Try

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  
<title>HOME</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown.css" type="text/css" >
```

instead.

IIRC Firefox does not read the link to your css file if the tag is self closing, because it is presumed empty.

Comment: Closed LINK and META tags are entirely valid in normal HTML. You just don't **have** to do it.

Comment: @ ceejayoz: read more closely. I said Firefox does not like it. It's a fact, try it.